# OMDb API ordenação itens dicionario python

Tags: python, api, request

Preciso fazer um programa que dado determinado nome, retorne o nome do filme e o ano em que foi lançado usando a api OMDb, e ordenar pelo ano de lançamento. Eu consegui listar os filmes porem não estou conseguindo ordenar pelo ano de lançamento, por se tratar de um dicionário, já tentei de tudo até mesmo o OrderedDict mas não funciona ou estou usando errado, se alguém puder me ajuda ficarei grato.

```
import requests
import json
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

def requisicao(nome):
    try:
        req = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=5b5be94f&type=movie&s='+nome)
        return req
    except:
        print('Erro de conexão')
        return None


while True:
    nome = input('Digite o nome do filme ou EXIT para sair: ')
    if nome == 'EXIT':
        exit()
    else:
        result = requisicao(nome)
        dic = json.loads(result.text)
        #OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
        for i in dic['Search']:
            print("Titulo: " + i['Title'] + "\n" "Ano: " + i['Year'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função de ordenação `sorted()`, ela permite passar um parâmetro `key=` contendo uma função que serve para definir a chave da ordenação.

No caso podemos usar `operator.itemgetter` para criar uma função que extrai um ou mais ítens do objeto a ser ordenado, o que seria perfeito para passar para o `sorted()`:

```
import operator
for i in sorted(dic['Search'], key=operator.itemgetter('Year')):
    print("Titulo:", i['Title'])
    print("Ano:", i['Year'])
```

Comment: Olá @nosklo. Tente detalhar mais a sua resposta, explicar o que faz.

Comment: @JoãoMartins feito, espero que esteja mais claro

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado @nosklo